# Making native Kubeless calls via REST

Tags: node.js, rest, curl, kubernetes, serverless-framework

I want to submit a function (via http-trigger) from a NodeJS process to kubeless but I do not want to use the javascript equivalent of

```
curl --data '{"term":"Albemarle"}' localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/bikesearch/ --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

because that needs me to know the actual IP address of the service running the function. I want to be able to access the kubeless api that gives me the level of indirection by just knowing the name of the function

```
kubeless function call bikesearch --data '{"term":"Albemarle"}'
```

Is there anyway to access the above ( function call ) api via node?

Answer (score 1):

kubeless also creates services for functions, so you should able to just do a http get to `http://bikesearch:8080` if your DNS setup is working and your application is in the same namespace. If you are in another namespace you need to use a more qualified name, e.g. `bikesearch.<function-namespace>svc.cluster.local`

If you want to call the function from outside the k8s cluster, you might want to create an Ingress with `kubeless ingress create...`

Answer (score 0):

If DNS is correctly configured for your cluster, you can also directly access the Kubernetes master under the `kubernetes` DNS name.

Another way is [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment-variables/). Kubernetes itself is registered as a service, so you can use the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable.

For newer Kubernetes versions you have to authenticate, so have a look at [how to access the API server from within a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod).